# How to hide/show if the user choose the option tag then clicks the button

Tags: jquery, html

I have here the html code. What I want is that if the user selects wether client or agency option, then clicks the next button. The class clientS or agencyS will be displayed.

```html
<span>I am a *
  <select class="selectpicker" name="type">
   <option></option>
   <option id="agency" name="agency" value="Agency">Agency</option>
   <option id="client" name="client" value="Client">Client</option>
  </select>

    <input class='hide clientS' type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
    <input class='hide clientS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
 <input class='hide clientS' type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required/>

    <!--The other inputs I want to display if the option selected is the Agency!-->

    <input class='hide agencyS' type="text" name="agencyname" placeholder="Agencyname" required/>
    <input class='hide agencyS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
 <input class='hide agencyS' type="text" name="addrs" placeholder="Address" required/>

    <input type="button" name="btn" class="next action-button" value="Next">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
$('.agencyS').hide(); //default agencyS hidden
$('.clientS').hide(); //default clientS hidden
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (select.value === 'Agency') {
        // if user selects Agent
        $('.agencyS').show(); //agencyS Show
        $('.clientS').hide(); //clientS hidden
    } else if (select.value === 'Client') {
        // if user clientS Agent
        $('.clientS').show(); //clientS Show
        $('.agencyS').hide(); //agencyS hidden
    } else {
        $('.clientS').hide();
        $('.agencyS').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>I am a *
<select class="selectpicker" name="type">
   <option></option>
   <option id="agency" name="agency" value="Agency">Agency</option>
   <option id="client" name="client" value="Client">Client</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="btn" class="next action-button" value="Next">
<br />
<input class='clientS' type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
<input class='clientS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<input class='clientS' type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required/>
<input class='agencyS' type="text" name="agencyname" placeholder="Agencyname" required/>
<input class='agencyS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<input class='agencyS' type="text" name="addrs" placeholder="Address" required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to hide the `.hide` class by default. Then you'll want to add an event listener to the button which, on click, triggers a function that checks what the `.value` of the `<select>` is. Based on what the value is, you can `.show()` the relevant content (`.agencyS` or `.clientS`). Note that you'll probably also want to `.hide()` the inverse option, in case the user picks the wrong one initially.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (select.value === 'Agency') {
    $('.agencyS').show();
    $('.clientS').hide();
  } else if (select.value === 'Client') {
    $('.clientS').show();
    $('.agencyS').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>I am a *
<select class="selectpicker" name="type">
  <option></option>
  <option id="agency" name="agency" value="Agency">Agency</option>
  <option id="client" name="client" value="Client">Client</option>
</select>
    
<input type="button" name="btn" class="next action-button" value="Next">

<br />

<input class='hide clientS' type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
<input class='hide clientS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<input class='hide clientS' type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required/>

<input class='hide agencyS' type="text" name="agencyname" placeholder="Agencyname" required/>
<input class='hide agencyS' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<input class='hide agencyS' type="text" name="addrs" placeholder="Address" required/>
```

Comment: Your answer works correctly as the OP needs. But you're using both `jQuery` and plain `JavaScript` at the same time. So kindly, I suggest editing your answer and use only `jQuery` as of the OP has tagged his question with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".agencyS,.clientS").hide();
    $("[name='btn']").click(function(v){
        $(".agencyS,.clientS").hide();
        if(v=$(".selectpicker").val()) {
            $("."+v.toLowerCase()+"S").show();
        };
    });
});
```

[Test it live!](http://jsfiddle.net/21oghqpb/7/)

Comment: Oh! I edit my answer to hide elems at first. check it and its fiddle (Live sample).